# Keep on getting SDK error message

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I have been working on Android Studio for a while now. But today when I tried to create a new project, I got the following error message:

> Your Android SDK is out of date or is missing templates. Please ensure
>   you are using SDK version 22 or later. You can configure your SDK via
>   Configure | Project Defaults | Project Structure | SDKs

I upgraded my SDK tools, android studio. I have also configured my sdk location in studio as per the message, but to no avail.

[image: SDK Manager]

[image: Android Studio]

Comment: If you close your project, then go to "Configure | Project Defaults | Project Structure | SDKs", what are the SDKs listed there?

Comment: It lists all the sdks that I have mapped. It list sdk of Android studio and also I have downloaded android sdk separately and this also gets reflected as I tried to map it.

Comment: This was basically a path issue. Once JAVA_HOME was set properly, this error disappeared. This PATH variable was needed for SDK itself and not for any project.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have faced the same issue, to solve it:
1- delete (or move) the projects folder (`AndroidStudioProjects`).
2- Run the Android-Studio (a WELCOME screen will started).
3- From Welcome Screen choose, "`Configure` -> `Project Defaults` -> `Project Structure`)
4- Under `Platform Settings` choose `SDKs`.
5- Select `Android SDK` -> right_click `delete`.
6- `Right_click` -> `New Sdk` -> `Android SDK` -> choose your `SDK dir` -> then `OK`.
7- Choose the `Build target` -> `apply` -> `OK`. enjoy

Comment: If you have an open project, do `File` > `Close Project` to get back to the welcome screen and trigger the SDK download.

Answer (score 3):

SDK files are not included in the Android Studio distribution package android-studio-ide-135.1538390-windows.zip. You have to manually add them, for instance from the adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip file.

Comment: yes, just download the standalone sdk package under the GET THE SDK FOR AN EXISTING IDE section in this: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download

Answer (score 1):

In the case: if your project sdk is already set and was running properly.

and after that it gives error like: "please select your sdk" then just copy same android sdk folder to different folder and set that new android sdk path to your project and rebuild your project,it will fix the issue, then again change your project android sdk path to old path and rebuild project.

Comment: after setting old path again and it works properly then delete the copied sdk to new folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue the i came to understand that the android studio was not able to create folder so i ran the studio as sudo

`cd  /opt/android-studio/bin` then run  `sudo bash studio.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue with Studio 2.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.
What actually helped me: close the Studio; rename SDK folder; open the Studio; enter a new path in prompt dialog.