# Error while using the android studio for first time

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04

I loaded the android studio into my ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit system.
I load as in the step in[this link](http://www.linux.com/community/blogs/132-mobile/779326-mobile-development-how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu-version-1404)

And as soon as I opened that i encountered a error as

[image: error:]

Then i tied to solve the problem as in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794272/android-sdk-is-missing-out-of-date-or-is-missing-templates-please-ensure-you)

1- delete (or move) the projects folder (AndroidStudioProjects).

2- Run the Android-Studio (a WELCOME screen will started).

3- From Welcome Screen choose, "Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure)

4- Under Platform Settings choose SDKs.

But when i reached the step 4 i did not find platform settings instead i found this window after clicking project structure

[image: window]

As i did not find any platform setting if i click on browse (...) button under android SDK location i landed on this.

[image: window]

And i don't know how to move further, please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be in the directory where you installed android-studio like:

```
android-studio/sdk
```

If you already had the android sdk with eclipse or something, you could also point it at that one, saving you from downloading all the libraries again.

you should just set an environment variable called ANDROID_HOME to the sdk location and I think that field defaults to android_home, but can't remember.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the next solution at the link you referenced. [Android SDK is missing, out of date, or is missing templates. Please ensure you are using SDK version 22 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794272/android-sdk-is-missing-out-of-date-or-is-missing-templates-please-ensure-you)? 
That solution worked for me.

I had same issue in Android Studio 3. (the project was open) so I closed the current project and the IDE automatically prompted to download the latest components. once its done everything was working correctly.