# Android Studio Error when Creating New Project

Tags: android-studio

I started the Android Studio and tried to create New Project and got the error.
[Click Here for Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgaFv.png)
The error is: Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or missing templates. But, Android SDK is already installed in the directory.

Comment: It looks like SDK path error.
Did you try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794272/android-sdk-is-missing-out-of-date-or-is-missing-templates-please-ensure-you)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you Android SDK is having problems. 
Have you checked already?

Steps:

- On the bottom right of the Menu, Click on "configure"
- Check if the location of your SDK is correct.
- If the problem persists, try to reinstall the Android Studio.