# Android sdk installation query

Tags: android

I know it's a very nuisance question for many of you but due to some problem I am not able to install android sdk. I have installed sdk in a android studio folder in c drive but whenever I am opening android studio application I get a message which says "your android sdk is missing, out of date or corrupted". Can you suggest what should I do?

Comment: go with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794272/android-sdk-is-missing-out-of-date-or-is-missing-templates-please-ensure-you

Comment: `what should I do` - how about searching? Have you tried it? There are already 1000 questions about your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the path of your android sdk to your 'path' variables (assuming you are using windows)

Go to

1. Control Panel --> System and Security --> System Click on Advanced system settings
2. Then Click Environment Variables
3. There go to the System Variables area and locate the Path variable, select it + click Edit...
4. Add the folder of the SDK location and Click OK a few
   times

Then restart Android Studio

Comment: I tried that but then also I am not able to start a new project on android studio. Is there any other solution?