# Android studio SDK manager is missing

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, sdk

I am following [this ionic tutorial](https://ionicacademy.com/get-started-with-ionic/) and having some trouble with setting up the SDK in Android Studio in order to test my ionic project.
I am looking for the SDK manager however it seems to be missing. When I select the configure drop down menu there should be an `SDK manager` option however it is absent (as you can see in the following image):

[image: configure]

Likewise when I select `settings > Appearance and Behaviour > System settings`, `Android SDK` should be an option here.

[image: settings]

I tried selecting project structure and adding a new SDK [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794272/android-sdk-is-missing-out-of-date-or-is-missing-templates-please-ensure-you) however `Android SDK` was not an option as you can see in the following image.

[image]

Note: I had installed Android Studio a few years ago and it was working but uninstalled it again. I've tried to make sure everything was cleaned out before installing it again (i.e deleted the AndroidStudioProjects folder that was left) however I'm not sure what else to look for.

Also If there is another way I can test my ionic build (as opposed to downloading android studio) then I would be grateful if you could advise.
Thank for any help.

Comment: which android studio you can use ???

Comment: it's version 3.1.3

Comment: your sdk path is not right please check perfectly

Comment: apparently that's where android studio installs the sdk folder. however there is no sdk folder in the location when I check. I searched on my computer for an sdk folder but it is nowhere.

Comment: Please go on **C:ProgramFiles**  in this folder check any android folder available or not and please also check **ProgramFiles(x84)**. May be SDK is install hear please check

Comment: Thanks. Android Studio is in Program Files however there is no sdk folder. and I checked Program Files x86 also.

Comment: Download Android SDK from https://developer.android.com/studio/

Comment: dear please uninstall the android studio and delete all folder of the android where show on **C:/ProgramFiles** & **C:ProgramFiles(x86)** path and download android studio from hear https://developer.android.com/studio/ and install it again. @Sarah

Comment: ahhhh great! I deleted the empty Android folder where the sdk folder should be installed (C:\Users\Sarah\AppData\Local\Android) and I am re-installing Android Studio. It seems to be installing properly now as the sdk components are being installed. The last time I installed it, it did not show the sdk components being installed. Great thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 17):

It's actually on the Welcome screen now, under the *Configure* menu

[image: sdk manager in android studio]

I couldn't find it from within the IDE when editing a project. If you have a project open, be sure to click File / Close Project to return to the Welcome screen.

Comment: Why in the **** did they put it there? So annoying... Is it possible to access it from somewhere else?

Comment: It's still there, but buried: File -> Settings... -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK. Also, once I had finally completed a successful build of my imported project, the SDK Manager and AVD Manager finally appeared under Tools.

Answer (score 15):

You have accidently disabled `Android Support` plugin in your plugin list. Try enable it and restart Android Studio.

To be detailed: In your first picture, `Configure` -> `Plugins`, tick almost everything to enable (for me which is also using Android Studio 3.1.3, there are `Android Support`, `Android APK Support`, `Firebase Services`, `Google Developers Samples`, `Firebase App Indexing`, `Firebase Testing`, `Test Recorder`, `Google Services`, `Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio`, `Android NDK Support`, `Android Games` and `App Links Assistant`), then `OK` to `Restart` Android Studio.

Comment: This one saved my day! Thanks!

Comment: this lead me to 'project structure -> suggestion' node to update some items followed after 'app'node  there. After the window closed Android studio started sync automatically. Upvoting certainly.

Comment: Android Support doesn't appear under the Plugins Marketplace or Installed...

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps after uninstalling previous version of Android studio:

1. Download SDK zip file from here --> [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools)
2. Extract the zip file.
3. Copy and paste that extracted folder into Applications/Android Studio/
4. Open Android Studio. Go to: (Quick Start) / Configure / Project Defaults / Project 
   Structure / (Android SDK Location) and browse SDK folder.
5. Apply and save.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this: Should I extract the sdk to the folder specified: C:\Users\Sarah\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Comment: I don't see a zip file on that link?

Comment: When I installed Android Studio, no wizard came up to install sdk packages (as shown in the video on the link you gave me).

Comment: @Sarah  did u find the SDK folder?

Comment: I followed what Mohammad said in the comments above and uninstalled android studio then deleted the empty Android folder at this location C:\Users\Sarah\AppData\Local\Android. I then reinstalled Android Studio and it installed the sdk components successfully. So the reason it hadnt installed correctly was because of the empty Android folder that was left from previous installations. Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

If SDK Manager is missing. But SDK is installed.
then you need install Sdk manager command line.

To open the SDK Manager from Android Studio, click Tools > SDK Manager or click SDK Manager in the toolbar. If you're not using Android Studio, you can download tools using the **sdkmanager command-line tool.**