# Android Studio problems when creating new app

Tags: android-studio

I'm a new mem here and I'm having a problem with Android Studio.
When I start my project with this software, its Interface had currently changed: "Create New Project" instead of "Start a new Android Studio project" likes usual. 
And even creating app steps were also not like before. Here are the problem's pictures:

[image: "Create New Project"]

[image: Creating App Steps]

Please help me soon, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio SDK manager is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222065/android-studio-sdk-manager-is-missing)

Answer (score 1):

You have accidently disabled `Android Support` plugin. Re-enable it in `Configure` -> `Plugins`, and tick almost every plugin, then `OK` to restart Android Studio.

Comment: @Zoe Thanks, I want to "express" something like "inline quote". Is just use the plain text without format OK?

Comment: If you mean an actual quote, there's separate formatting for that. Either use a quote block, or use `"` if it's inline. You can generally use `"` for a lot of things aside actual quotes though. For stuff like `Android Support`, I left that because I'm not entirely sure what the alternative is, but you could probably use quotation marks for it.

Comment: @Zoe "Android Support" is a plugin name in the "Plugins" list, "Configure" is shown in the first picture in the question, "Plugins" is the menu from "Configure", "OK" is the positive button in the settings window, "Restart" is the positive button of popup window ("Restart Android Studio to activate changes in plugins?") after "OK" is clicked. This is all the reasons why I code format these words. Sometimes I wrote an answer with full of code format, I think it is not good, but I have no idea when to remove them.