# How do I configure Android SDKs for Android Studio 3.2.1?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I downloaded the latest version (3.2.1) of Android Studio from the [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/studio/) site.

After installing the application, it won't start. I get an error message when clicking on "Start a new Android Studio project":

> Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted.

I read an [outdated post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794272/android-sdk-is-missing-out-of-date-or-is-missing-templates-please-ensure-you) dealing with the same issue but an older version of the application. I followed the solution described there and got stuck after navigating to Configure > Project Defaults > Project Structure. This is the window I see right now:

[image]

I can't find the SDK. Where is it located? Does it not get installed together with the app? If so, where can I download it from?

Comment: Are you sure that the path of your SDK does not contain any whitespaces? there is an error in the provided screen. For windows the default SDK location is `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` for mac `~\Library\Android` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: For the JDK problem just check the `"Use embedded JDK (recomended)"`

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, the SDK path is **empty** and there is **no** SDK installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't find the SDK. Where is it located? Does it not get installed
>   together with the app? If so, where can I download it from?

That depends on how you installed the Android Studio. With the SDK packages (called bundle) or you have installed it separately which doesn't have SDK packages.

> Where is it located

It's mostly uses:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Directory on windows if you install SDK Manager, it will be easy to figured out.

> where can I download it from

After installing Android SDK Manager, you'll need to download some packages like;

- Platform-tools
- Build-tools
- Support library

And etc

To be able to compile-use Android Studio which is a general question and use [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20setup%20android%20sdk%20manager&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIR817IR817&oq=how%20to%20setup%20android%20sdk%20manager&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4824j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for that.

Comment: There is no folder named Android in `C:\Users\Wais\AppData\Local`. You also stated that I need to download some packages, but where from? A website? Using npm?

Comment: Have you installed SDK manager? You can download the packages with SDK manager so you won’t need anything else. Simple :)

Comment: I tried doing that, but it fails everytime. I get an error: "Cannot download ...". Anyways I downloaded a zip file from [here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip), but I have no idea where to place its contents. Can you help me?

Comment: Sure. It sounds like your IP has an issue. Maybe it is blocked or there is an issue with the internet connection. That package should be placed in `<your installed sdk address which can be found in top of the SDK manager>/extras` and then unzip the file in there. You can however opening the sdk manager in Android Studio then try to install platforms and etc.

Comment: Yes, it is my IP (I downloaded the files using a VPN). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Anytime, glad to help. Like I said, if you use Android Studio to open the SDK manager, it will download everything it's needed and it's a better choice to download those packages like emulators or etc.

Comment: OK I will try doing that. Thanks again!