# Android SDK is missing "Android Studio"

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, mobile

I have installed android studio and installed flutter on it. But when I try to make any project, this error message appears:

> "Your Android SDK is missing, out of date, or corrupted."

So I tried to download it from the android studio, but this error appeared

> "Nothing to do! Android SDK is up to date. SDK emulator directory is
> missing"

So, I need help, because I don't know what to do.

Comment: Do you see Android SDK Tools under Tools –> SDK manager –> SDK tools? You may need to deselect Hide obsolete packages to see it.

Comment: See This : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794272/android-sdk-is-missing-out-of-date-or-is-missing-templates-please-ensure-you

Comment: We have 2 SDK package for first time that you install the flutter Android studio be confused between 2 SDK but if you set them correct for one time it will be OK.