# android studio - SDK manager updating SDK Tools even its manually downloading in directory

Tags: android, sdk

android SDK Manager fail to download and update tools.

even after I downloaded all platform-toos and SDK-tools, and point out its location then nothing was happening only it provides output something like this

Nothing to do!
Android SDK is up to date...
SDK emulator directory is missing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android SDK is missing, out of date, or is missing templates. Please ensure you are using SDK version 22 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794272/android-sdk-is-missing-out-of-date-or-is-missing-templates-please-ensure-you)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

after following some solutions from internet but nothing works out, I was aware that we had proxy and i place it on "outomatic configuration url" test proxy connection and say connected.

in android studio->tool->SDK Manager->Android SDK Location click edit and provide its location where all SDK tools i downloaded click next then nothing happen

I change my proxy from "outomatic configuration url" to Manual and provide username & password where username and password is the same as your login in windows then again repeat: studio->tool->SDK Manager->Android SDK Location, and it work

conclusion: SDK manager wasn't actually using yung download SDK instead download it anew so delete it before running SDK Manager similar to what @Khanh-Tran suggested