# How to set jdk in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

when I worked in Android studio suddenly  my computer is turn off and then i turn on again my computer and open Android studio ,it has a problem that ,android studio unknown java classes and doesn't import anything.
[image]

how can i solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do:

1) Clean the project

If you want to set the `JDK` to your project you should right click on `File->Project Structure` and on `SDK Location` select the JDK you want to use.

Comment: You should also check your SDK if is all set.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805813/keep-on-getting-sdk-error-message